# MySQL command to view records on 15 minutes basis

Tags: mysql, syntax

I want to select some records on the basis of 15 minutes time interval. Is it possible using any sql command. I am confused while doing it with div 900 sec and timestamp. Please help.

Comment: do you mean you want to query for data between two times of a date field column? And their interval should be in 15 mins?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking here. Do you want a set of rows with dates between {specific_time} and {specific_time+15m}? Rows with dates between {now} and {now-15m}? Data grouped in 15 minute intervals? Is "timestamp" a column you are trying to filter or group by or are you meaning the value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` at the time? _It would probably help most to provide a small amount of sample data and what you want the output to be for that data._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MINUTE()` function.

```
    SELECT *  FROM <TABLE NAME> WHERE MINUTE(<DATETIME/TIMESTAMP COLUMN>) % 15 = 0
```